# xPath values returned are stuck together

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I'm using stringbuilder to create an expression, when it returns values, if a child has multiple subchilds, they return stuck together. I want them returned separated. What's wrong with my code?

```
Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument
Dim bldr As New StringBuilder
Dim crit As String
Dim val As String

bldr.Append("//View[@Name='")
bldr.Append(TextBox2.Text)
bldr.Append("']")
crit = bldr.ToString
xDoc.Load("d:\input.sample.xml")
val = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(crit).InnerText
TextBox3.Text = val
```

So in my xml that has this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Views ClientCode="Example">
    <View Name="vSample">
        <Criteria>SAMPLE1</Criteria>
        <Criteria>SAMPLE2</Criteria>
        <Criteria>SAMPLE3</Criteria>
        <Criteria>SAMPLE4</Criteria>
    </View>
</Views>
```

I'm having this returned:

```
SAMPLE1SAMPLE2SAMPLE3SAMPLE4
```

What I want is this:

```
SAMPLE1
SAMPLE2
SAMPLE3
SAMPLE4
```

Comment: Is your textbox configured for multi-line? There is also no guarantee that you will get newlines due to the XML may all be a single line. Best would probably be to select nodes and then iterate over them and build your value manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, but you can loop through the child nodes and add the innertext of each with a carriage return to val:

```
For Each item As XmlNode In xDoc.SelectSingleNode(crit).ChildNodes

    val += item.InnerText & vbCrLf

Next

TextBox3.Text = val
```

By just using `val = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(crit).InnerText`, that gets the innerText of all child nodes as one big string and it doesn't add line feeds (as you found).

I'm also pretty sure someone who has worked with this more will have a one-liner for it.

Answer (score 0):

change to use val = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(crit).InnerXml, and it should become clear you're selecting the parent element "View"

instead you could do:

```js
        Dim nodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes(crit + "/Criteria")

        For Each criteria As XmlNode In nodeList
            TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text + val + Constants.vbCrLf
        Next
```